# Tag a data to curl HTTP request in PHP C++ extension

Tags: php, zend-framework, php-extension, php-curl, php-internals

I have a PHP C++ extension that monitors the web requests and captures the required request details with Call stacks.

Here from my PHP C++ extension whenever `curl_exec(..)` happens and a HTTP  request is made to another PHP web application, I need to tag a data to the HTTP request that will be initiated/called and to retrieve the tagged data on the other side. How can i achieve this functionality.?

It is more of PHP internals. I am searching for some way to invoke the `curl_setopt` function from my PHP C++ extension and try to add a header in it  but I am not sure if that will help. Is there possibility for this ?

Or is there any other possibility to add data to the HTTP request and retrieve the same data into the Invoked HTTP request.? And most importantly i need to achieve this from my PHP extension written in C++.

Comment: Why not just add a custom header on the PHP side? Why "inject" it via an extension?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari I am working on a Profiler for PHP. I need to do it on the fly via extension.